# Run multiple commands automatically after opening command prompt

Tags: command-line

So I'm really new to this code thing. And i would like to know, how to automatically run commands when command prompt is open. So, what i usually do to run my application is that i open command prompt, the i go >cd desktop then >cd myapp, and then >node atv.js. But i have to do this everytime i need to run my application. Is there any simple way? or is there any way that in order to run those commands i just click on specific icon or folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a shortcut.

1. Right-click empty space in `C:\Users\<yourUsername>\Desktop\myapp`
2. Choose *New → Shortcut*
3. Enter `node atv.js` and continue
4. Enter any name you like and finish creating the shortcut
5. Move the shortcut to some handy location
6. Open shortcut's properties
7. In the *Start in* field enter `C:\Users\<yourUsername>\Desktop\myapp`

Comment: OMG Thank you so much!!! Thanks for quick response. You're the best.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to create a batch file, or 2.

Put your commands into first file RunNodeATV.bat

> cd desktop
>   cd myapp
>   node atv.js

In another batch file (StartRun.bat for example) put the command

> Start RunNodeATV.bat

When you execute the StartRun.bat file it will START the RunNodeATV.bat file in a new command window and it will stay open once complete.

Does this help?

Or just create a shortcut to do the script you want if you don't require the command prompt to stay open.